# VB : Is it possible to cast/convert from List(Of DataRow) to List(Of String)?

Tags: vb.net, list, datatable

I'm trying to solve a problem regarding types of list. First of all I have a stored procedure in my DB which does a select of a single column and I try to proceed it in my app in VB. By making a method function I declared a DataTable that loads through the SqlCommand(with the CloseConnection behavior). After that I publicly declared a List(Of String) which needs to be populated with the rows/items from the stored procedure that is on the way. Below is my snippet of the code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Try
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
            Else
                conn.Open()
                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("LoadCodes", conn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                Dim collection As New List(Of DataRow)
                collection = dt.AsEnumerable.ToList

                LPrefix = collection.Cast(Of String)()

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message + vbCritical)
        End Try
```

It's `LPrefix = collection.Cast(Of String)()` where I get an exception error telling me that I can't really convert it. The old fashion way is to iterate with for/for each loop but that's not what I want for best use of performance especially if the list will have thousands of rows from a single column. So basically I want to insert those items from that DataTable to the List(Of String) without using For/For Each loop.

Running on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Basically there's nothing wrong with looping over your collection to convert it. Do you really need a `List(Of String)` or could you just bind to your DataTable directly and let the framework handle the details?

Comment: Yes, indeed I need the list to be in String type for further reference because later on in my app I have some queries through other stored procedures that take values from this list of string and send it as parameters to the stored procedure for query purpose. Looks like there's no support of cast DataRow to String type thus the only option is to iterate with for/for each loop.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need your `collection` at all. Using LINQ, you can extract the first column directly out of your data table:

```
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))  
LPrefix = (From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
           Select row.Field(Of String)(0)).ToList()
```

Of course, this might use a loop internally, but since you want to *copy each value* into a list of strings, you *cannot* do it without looping through the data rows.

---

Another alternative would be to use an `IEnumerable(Of String)` instead of a `List(Of String)`:

```
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))  
Dim LPrefixNew As IEnumerable(Of String) = _
    From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Select row.Field(Of String)(0)
```

You can iterate through IEnumerable just as you would through a list, but evaluation is lazy: As long as you don't access the elements, the DataTable is not traversed. So, accessing this IEnumerable is like reading the elements directly from the DataTable, just in a more convenient way.

---

Another word of advice: You should not try to reason about performance until you have *measured* it. For example, your line `collection = dt.AsEnumerable.ToList` probably already loops through your entire DataTable and copies each DataRow reference into a List of DataRows; so, with this line, you *already have* the performance penalty that you are trying to avoid.

So, don't automatically assume that some `For` loop is always slower than some single statement. [Measure it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), *then* optimize.

Comment: +1 even better. Maybe this should even be condensed to Linq-to-Sql.

Comment: Yeah I'm very thankful to your post this indeed is one-other-way solution. Thanks aswell for the "measure it" suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `DataRow` only has one column you just need to instruct `ConvertAll` to cast it:

```
LPrefix = collection.ConvertAll(Function(x) x[0].ToString)
```

*Thanks to **Binary Worrier** for c#-2-vb translation!*

Comment: `LPrefix = collection.ConvertAll(Function(x) x[0].ToString)` or better `dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(x) x[0].ToString).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out - VB is way too talkative for my taste and the example on MSDN is rather confusing.

Comment: Tell me about it! We've a heap of legacy VB code here, and I'm more than comfortable with it. Thankfully we write most new code in C#, I find it amazing how much more productive I am with C#. _This is my personal opinion, I do want want to start a Vb v's C# flame war!_